# How to output json data from imap_open() function?

Tags: php, json

This is my php code

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(0);

    // Multiple email account
    $emails = array(
        array(
            'no' => '5',
            'label' => 'inbox 1',
            'host' => '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX',
            'username' => 'xxx@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'xxx'
        ),
        array(
            'no' => '2',
            'label' => 'Inbox Email 2',
            'host' => '{mail.domain.net:143/notls}INBOX',
            'username' => 'mail2@domain.net',
            'password' => 'xxxxxxxxxx'
        )
    );

    foreach ($emails as $email) {

        $read = imap_open($email['host'], $email['username'], $email['password']) or die('Cannot connect to yourdomain.com: ' . imap_last_error() . '</div>');

        $array = imap_search($read, 'SUBJECT "123"');

        if ($array) {

            $html = '';

            rsort($array);

            foreach ($array as $result) {


                $overview = imap_fetch_overview($read, $result, 0);
                $message  = imap_body($read, $result, 0);
                $reply    = imap_headerinfo($read, $result, 0);

                //Now I want a json output like bellow structure
                /*
                "email no":"1",//from emails array
                "email lebel":"label",//from emails arrey
                "subject" :"mail_subject",
                "date"    :"full date time",
                "message" :"messege",
                "sent_from":"sender email"
                */


            }

        }

        imap_close($read);

    }

    ?>
```

I want `json` output from fetched emails like the following structure:

```
"email no":"email no",
"email_label":"label",
"subject" :"mail_subject",
"date"    :"full date time",
"message" :"messege",
"sent_from":"sender email"
```

I don't know how to do that, if anybody write a example code that will very helpful for me

I tested it to print as normal using this code:

```
echo $overview[0]->from;
echo $overview[0]->date;
echo $overview[0]->subject;
echo $reply->from[0]->mailbox.'@'.$reply->from[0]->host;
echo $message;
```

and this is the output:

```
sahidul islam Sun, 23 Jun 2019 12:54:32 +0800123sahid4745@gmail.com--0000000000008222fd058bf67e3a Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8" Thi is test message --0000000000008222fd058bf67e3a Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
    Thi is test message
```

this part of the message `--0000000000008222fd058bf67e3a Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8" Thi is test message --0000000000008222fd058bf67e3a Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
    Thi is test message` may be be conflicting when output as `json_encode`, How do I extract `Thi is test message` from `$message`?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that here we can just assemble an array we desire to output, then `json_encode`:

```
$json_output = []; // output array to be JSONed

foreach ($emails as $email) {
    $read = imap_open($email['host'], $email['username'], $email['password']) or die('Cannot connect to yourdomain.com: ' . imap_last_error() . '</div>');
    $array = imap_search($read, 'SUBJECT "123"');

    if ($array) {
        $html = '';
        rsort($array);

        foreach ($array as $result) {

            $overview = imap_fetch_overview($read, $result, 0);
            $message = imap_body($read, $result, 0);
            $reply = imap_headerinfo($read, $result, 0);

            // data from email array
            $json_output["email no"] = $email["no"];
            $json_output["email label"] = $email["label"];

            // data from other variables
            $json_output["subject"] = $result["mail_subject"];
            $json_output["date"] = $result["full date time"];
            $json_output["message"] = $result["messege"];
            $json_output["sent_from"] = $result["sender email"];

            $json_output = json_encode($json_output, true);

        }

    }

    imap_close($read);
}
```

I was not sure, where the data comes from for these vars, which I'm sure you would know that:

```
$json_output["subject"] = $result["mail_subject"];
$json_output["date"] = $result["full date time"];
$json_output["message"] = $result["messege"];
$json_output["sent_from"] = $result["sender email"];
```

#### Extracting the Message

There should be better ways to extract the message, one of which would be:

```
$re = '/charset="UTF-8"\s*(.+?)\s+-/s';
$str = '--0000000000008222fd058bf67e3a Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8" Thi is test message --0000000000008222fd058bf67e3a Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
    Thi is test message';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
var_dump($matches);
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CaJ48O/1/)

Comment: I tried this way but problem in pursing message my pursed massage is "--0000000000008222fd058bf67e3a Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8" Thi is test message --0000000000008222fd058bf67e3a Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Thi is test message" so this is conflicting ,and I need to extract "this is test message" and problem on it